# limit drools cpu usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat7, drools

drools is very cpu intensive. When I unpacked the war file for either the kie server or the workbench, tomcat's cpu usage went up to 100%. is there any way to limit the cpu usage that occurs as a result of running these drools components?

Comment: Is there a way of limiting CPU usage for any process? Any Java program?

Comment: Containers are the way to go if you want to isolate your application processes. Try to assemble the tomcat inside Docker container, and configure the cgroups for the CPU limiting.